# How to preserve the order of the fields to be selected when using $query->addExpression()

Tags: mysql, drupal-7, dynamic-queries

I'm using Drupal 7 and I have to make a union on multiple tables. For the union to work some conditions have to be met:

1. same number of columns
2. same data type
3. same **order**

Some of the tables are missing a column so in order to compensate for that I just add it with something like this: `$query->addExpression(':field_1', 'field_1', array(':field_1' => NULL));`. So at this point condition 1 & 2 are satisfied, **but** the order of the fields in the select is different.

See example bellow:

```
  $query_1 = db_select('table_one', 't1');
  $query_1->fields('t1', array('field_1', 'field_2'));

  $query_2 = db_select('table_two', 't2');
  if (true) {
    $query_2->fields('t2', array('field_1'));
  } else {
    $query_2->addExpression(':field_1', 'field_1', array(':field_1' => NULL));
  }
  $query_2->fields('t2', array('field_2'));        

  $query_3 = db_select('table_three', 't3');
  if (false) {
    $query_3->fields('t3', array('field_1'));
  } else {
    $query_3->addExpression(':field_1', 'field_1', array(':field_1' => NULL));
  }
  $query_3->fields('t3', array('field_2'));
```

And the result is:

```
// dpq($query_1);
SELECT t1.field_1 AS field_1, t1.field_2 AS field_2
FROM {table_one} t1

// dpq($query_2);
SELECT t2.field_1 AS field_1, t2.field_2 AS field_2
FROM {table_two} t2

// dpq($query_3);
SELECT t3.field_2 AS field_2, '' AS field_1
FROM {table_three} t3

// dpq($query_1->union($query_2)->union($query_3));
SELECT t1.field_1 AS field_1, t1.field_2 AS field_2
FROM {table_one} t1 
UNION SELECT t2.field_1 AS field_1, t2.field_2 AS field_2
FROM {table_two} t2 
UNION SELECT t3.field_2 AS field_2, '' AS field_1
FROM {table_three} t3
```

Seems that using `$query->addExpression` will not guarantee the position of the field to be where you'd expect it to be. Look at the dump of the 3rd query where `addExpression` has been used. Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the only workaround I found to keep the order. Use an expression even if that field exists or not. That way the order is the one that you'd expect:

```
if (TRUE) {
  // To keep the order of the fields we have to use this hacky way.
  // Use a function that will not modify the string
  $query->addExpression("IFNULL(table_name.field_name, '')", 'field_name_alias');
} else {
  $query->addExpression(':field', 'field_name_alias', array(':field' => NULL));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to add a simplified example. For keep order of the fields instead of

```
$query->addField('n', 'uid', 'node_uid');
```

You can write

```
$query->addExpression('n.uid', 'node_uid');
```