# When using union placeholders seem to be replaced with values from the initial select used in the union

Tags: mysql, drupal-7, dynamic-queries

This is more or less related to this [How to preserve the order of the fields to be selected when using $query->addExpression()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11782454/how-to-preserve-the-order-of-the-fields-to-be-selected-when-using-query-addexp)

What I'm doing is making a `union` on multiple tables. But I also need to know from which table the values are coming from. So I just add something like this: `$query->addExpression(':table', 'table_name', array(':table' => $table_name));`

Problem is as soon as you make a union the table name is going to be replaced with that from the first query.

Check the example below:

```
$table_name = 'table_one'; 
$query_1 = db_select('table_one', 't1');
$query_1->fields('t1', array('field_1', 'field_2'));
$query_1->addExpression(':table', 'table_name', array(':table' => $table_name));

$table_name = 'table_two'; 
$query_2 = db_select('table_two', 't2');
$query_2->fields('t2', array('field_1', 'field_2'));
$query_2->addExpression(':table', 'table_name', array(':table' => $table_name));    

$table_name = 'table_three';
$query_3 = db_select('table_three', 't3');
$query_3->fields('t3', array('field_1', 'field_2'));
$query_3->addExpression(':table', 'table_name', array(':table' => $table_name));
```

If we check the selects individually they all look fine, you get the expected result, but when using union you will only see `table_one` all over the place.

```
// dpq($query_1) - OK 
SELECT t1.field_1 AS field_1, t1.field_2 AS field_2, 'table_one' AS table_name
FROM 
{table_one} t1

// dpq($query_2) - OK
SELECT t2.field_1 AS field_1, t2.field_2 AS field_2, 'table_two' AS table_name
FROM 
{table_two} t2

// dpq($query_3) - OK
SELECT t3.field_1 AS field_1, t3.field_2 AS field_2, 'table_three' AS table_name
FROM 
{table_three} t3

// dpq($query_1->union($query_2)->union($query_3)) - OOPS.. 'table_one' all over the place
SELECT t1.field_1 AS field_1, t1.field_2 AS field_2, 'table_one' AS table_name
FROM 
{table_one} t1 UNION SELECT t2.field_1 AS field_1, t2.field_2 AS field_2, 'table_one' AS table_name
FROM 
{table_two} t2 UNION SELECT t3.field_1 AS field_1, t3.field_2 AS field_2, 'table_one' AS table_name
FROM 
{table_three} t3
```

If you have ideas would be great because I've been banking my head for a while with this...

Comment: what if you try `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`?

Comment: Already tried that, no difference :( `SELECT t1.field_1 AS field_1, t1.field_2 AS field_2, 'table_one' AS table_name
FROM 
{table_one} t1 UNION ALL SELECT t2.field_1 AS field_1, t2.field_2 AS field_2, 'table_one' AS table_name
FROM 
{table_two} t2 UNION ALL SELECT t3.field_1 AS field_1, t3.field_2 AS field_2, 'table_one' AS table_name
FROM 
{table_three} t3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few hours of sleep I tracked it down to this function:

```
  // @file includes/database/select.inc
  public function arguments() {
    // ....

    // If there are any dependent queries to UNION,
    // incorporate their arguments recursively.
    foreach ($this->union as $union) {
      $args += $union['query']->arguments();
    }

    return $args;
  }
```

And since all the selects in the query have the same key `:table` then you'll end up with only one argument instead of thee.

***Solution***: Just make sure you use **different keys for the placeholders**.

So if we replace in the above example these lines (notice `:table_1` & `:table_2` instead of `:table`:

```
$query_2->addExpression(':table_1', 'table_name', array(':table_1' => $table_name));
$query_3->addExpression(':table_2', 'table_name', array(':table_2' => $table_name));
```

Voila, finally get the expected results. Hope it helps somebody, half a day lost trying to figure out why this was happening.

```
SELECT t1.field_1 AS field_1, t1.field_2 AS field_2, 'table_one' AS table_name
FROM 
{table_one} t1 UNION ALL SELECT t2.field_1 AS field_1, t2.field_2 AS field_2, 'table_two' AS table_name
FROM 
{table_two} t2 UNION ALL SELECT t3.field_1 AS field_1, t3.field_2 AS field_2, 'table_three' AS table_name
FROM 
{table_three} t3
```